# Good books to learn Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop, amazon-web-services

I would like to know about some good books that can help me to begin with AWS quickly and some books that can help me in learning AWS properly.My actual goal is to set up a Hadoop cluster using EC2 & S3.

Comment: Don't SHOUT your question titles. Have you tried reading Amazon's own AWS docs? http://aws.amazon.com/

Comment: Hello Marc..It was not intentional..and I am going through the documentation and videos..I just wanted to have some opinions from the experts as I am just starting it off..Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there are any books just to cover AWS-EC2.

"My actual goal is to set up a Hadoop cluster using EC2 & S3."

AWS- EC2 takes away that complexity (or ability!) of setting up your own cluster to run your Hadoop jobs.

There are two ways you can start Hadoop cluster using EC2 dynamic and static

In dynamic mode you start a new cluster to run your hadoop job and save your output on S3 (or somewhere) cluster will disappear once your job is finished.

In static mode cluster will be stay live and you can connect to further analysis.
You can also submit new Hadoop jobs to existing cluster.

Check their ruby client “`elastic-mapreduce`” manual for further details.

Example parameter you can pass to `elastic-mapreduce`

`--create` : to create a new cluster

`--alive` : to leave it alive after finishing the job

`--num-instances`: number of nodes in cluster

`--instance-type` : type of each task tracker/ data node small/big

`-j` : To submit job to existing cluster. you just need to pass job_id

[More details](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/GettingStartedGuide/Essentials.html)